# Ошибка при тестирования роли Ansible с помощью molecule

Tags: ansible, yaml

Пытаюсь научиться пользоваться средством тестирования ролей molecule. Тестирование происходит в виртуальной среде venv.

Python version - 3.5.3.

Инстанс - ubuntu 18.04, driver - docker.

Старт теста происходит гладко, при выполнении первого таска вываливается стена ошибок типа:

```
Exception ignored in: <function WeakValueDictionary.__init__.<locals>.remove at 0x7f6778372f28>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/weakref.py", line 117, in remove
```

Далее все выполняется по сценарию:

```
PLAY [Create] ******************************************************************

    TASK [Log into a Docker registry] **********************************************
    skipping: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'instance', 'image': 'ubuntu:bionic', 'pre_build_image': True})

    TASK [Check presence of custom Dockerfiles] ************************************
    ok: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'instance', 'image': 'ubuntu:bionic', 'pre_build_image': True})

    TASK [Create Dockerfiles from image names] *************************************
    skipping: [localhost] => (item={'name': 'instance', 'image': 'ubuntu:bionic', 'pre_build_image': True})

    TASK [Discover local Docker images] ********************************************
    ok: [localhost] => (item={'changed': False, 'skip_reason': 'Conditional result was False', 'skipped': True, 'item': {'name': 'instance', 'image': 'ubuntu:bionic', 'pre_build_image': True}, 'i': 0, 'ansible_loop_var': 'item', 'ansible_index_var': 'i'})
```

И на стадии converge выдает еще одну ошибку:

```
fatal: [instance]: FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {},
    "changed": false,
    "failed_modules": {
        "setup": {
            "ansible_facts": {
                "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
            },
            "failed": true,
            "module_stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/python: not found\nread unix @->/var/run/docker.sock: read: connection reset by peer\n",
            "module_stdout": "",
            "msg": "The module failed to execute correctly, you probably need to set the interpreter.\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
            "rc": 1,
            "warnings": [
                "No python interpreters found for host instance (tried ['/usr/bin/python', 'python3.7', 'python3.6', 'python3.5', 'python2.7', 'python2.6', '/usr/libexec/platform-python', '/usr/bin/python3', 'python'])"
            ]
        }
    },
    "msg": "The following modules failed to execute: setup\n"
}

    PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
    instance                   : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

ERROR:
```

После этого сценарий заканчивается, удаляются все внесенные изменения.

Сценарий molecule:

```
---
dependency:
  name: galaxy
lint:
  yamllint .
driver:
  name: docker
platforms:
  - name: instance
    image: ubuntu:bionic
    pre_build_image: true
provisioner:
  name: ansible
  log: true
  options:
    vvv: true
    diff: true
verifier:
  name: ansible
  converge_sequence:
    - create
    - converge
  idempotence_sequence:
    - create
    - converge
```

Не могли бы ли вы подсказать, в чем может заключаться проблема(да, я вижу, что ругается ошибка на интерпретатор)?

Comment: Внутрь контейнера можешь сделать запуск модуля `setup`? Ну и выхлоп сюда конечно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ оказался простым. Была проблема с пакетом docker-py. Вычистил старую версию, установил новую, накатил питон версии 3.8, все завелось.